# How to make border "line connected with a dot" and repeat with pseudo elements?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: absolute;
  top: 163px;
  left: 120px;
  height: 240px;
}

.wrapper:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: solid #00B1F1;
  border-width: 0 0 0 4px;
}
h3 {
  margin: 0px;

}

.circle {
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
  border: 2px solid #c1c1c1;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-bottom: 8%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #Ffffff;
  /* color of background */
}

.aboutContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.education {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 80%;
}

h2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  margin: 69px 0 38px;
  font-size: 1.9rem;
}
h3 {

}
.years {
  width: 20%;
  height: 90%;
  margin-right: 11%;
}

.year {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #00B1F1;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 93px;
  height: 33px;
  font-size: 0.87rem;
  color: $color2;
  margin-bottom: 124px;
}

.infoContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  height: 90%;
}

.experiance {
  width: 50%;
  height: 80%;
}

h2 {
  flex-direction: column;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: gray;
}


.yearInfo {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}
```

```html
<section class="aboutContainer">

      <div class="education">
        <h2>Education</h2>

        <div class="years">
          <div class="year">
            2017 - 2018
          </div>
          <div class="year">
            2018 - 2019
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="infoContainer">
          <div class="yearInfo">
            <h3>Web Developing Journey</h3>
            <p>Journey starts with The ICT College. First thing we came across was HTML and CSS and our first "Hello World".
              </p>
          </div>
          <div class="yearInfo">
            <h3>Web Developing Journey</h3>
            <p>Journey starts with The ICT College. First thing we came across was HTML and CSS and our first "Hello World".
</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div>


    </section>
```

I'm making my portfolio website from a PSD and I came across a left border with "Long line dot, long line dot". How can I make it?

I have tried making it and when I make something that closely resembles it, it results in not being responsive and the whole height from the lines change and it moves left right from the place.

Should I do it with pseudo elements or with border-left? Or should I use an image instead? I can't seem to figure this out for days. Could someone explain to me how to do it? Thank you in advance.

This is how it should look and not to change rapidly in height and it even moves left or right from the place.
[Border: line dot, line dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ThiD.png)

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. The policy of this site is to show your effort to solve the problem. That means you would have to provide your code to better help and to see what exactly you are having trouble with.

Comment: Could you post the code from what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that content as an unordered list.  We can write the html as a list, then style it so there's a blue border on the left of the list, with grey bullets overlapping.

There's little we can do with the styling of bullet-points in css lists.  Fortunately, we can use an image file for these.  Rather than adding a separate .png file, I've encoded it into the css.

Once we've put that in place  it's just a matter of positioning the elements within the list relative to the bullet point.

```css
ul   {margin-left:200px; border-left:5px solid #99f; list-style-position: inside;
     list-style-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABkAAAAfAgMAAABv3o7tAAAADFBMVEXBw8Dd4N3u8e39//z1rD+PAAAAAWJLR0QAiAUdSAAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB+MFAggcCa9VMDYAAAAdaVRYdENvbW1lbnQAAAAAAENyZWF0ZWQgd2l0aCBHSU1QZC5lBwAAAFNJREFUCNdj+A8GBxhIp5+Ggel/Dgz1IPoLA4M0iL7AwMAOohsYGBhBtAMDA8P+Awz/gBRDPRptj0aDxB0gNEwf3JwHUHNh9vxzYKyHuCOKDPcDANOllFiDB55zAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');}
li   {margin-left:-23px; position:relative; font-family:arial; margin-top:50px; left:-32px;}
time {position: absolute; left:-110px; top:7px;}
h3   {margin-top:-30px; padding-left:50px;}
p    {padding-left:50px;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>    
    <h3>Master of Engineering</h3>
    <time>2017 - 2018</time>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
      <h3>Sed ut perspiciatis</h3>
      <time>2016 - 2017</time>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
      <h3>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem</h3>
      <time>2015 - 2016</time>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This gives us clean, semantic HTML and a responsive layout.

Comment: Thank you. I would never have thought of doing it that way with lists. It's much better this way.